# Optimizing DP in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, optimization, dynamic-programming

I have the following DP which I am applying on a binarized image (either 0 or 1) in Matlab

```
[x, y] = size(img);
dp = zeros(x, y);
dp(1,:) = img(1,:);
dp(:,1) = img(:,1);
for i = 2:x
    for j = 2:y
        if img(i, j) == 0
            dp(i, j) = min([dp(i, j - 1), dp(i - 1, j), dp(i - 1, j - 1)]) + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

The code for large x and y takes a lot of time maybe because of the `if` condition and using `for` loops instead of writing vectorized code.

Can anyone optimize it.?
Or is there any approach which optimizes the above code by exploiting the fact that the matrix `img` contains either 0 or 1 (fewer 1s than 0s).
Also is it possible to somehow use parallel for loops to speed up.?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, you cannot really speed up this computation in general. But if you know that there are only very few entries where `img(i,j)==0` following approach might save you a little bit of time:

```
[x, y] = size(img);
dp = zeros(x, y);
dp(1,:) = img(1,:);
dp(:,1) = img(:,1);
[i, j] = find(img(2:end, 2:end) == 0); % Extract only these pixels where we actually need to do something
i = i + 1; %correct for removing the first row and column
j = j + 1;
for k = 1:numel(i);
    dp(i(k), j(k)) = min([dp(i(k), j(k) - 1), dp(i(k) - 1, j(k)), dp(i(k) - 1, j(k) - 1)]) + 1;
end
```

Comment: Actually there are fewer entries where `img(i,j) == 1` (although not much fewer).